# Fill a combobox that is on Freemarker template

Tags: java, html, combobox, freemarker

I'm trying to load data on a combobox which is stored in a `List<ArrayList<String>>` called `column`.

This is my code for charge data on template:

```
List<ArrayList<String>> columna = con.getColumn("table", "column");
Iterator<ArrayList<String>> iter = columna.iterator();
String name= null;
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    ArrayList<String> row = iter.next();
    for(int i=0; i<row.size(); i++) {
        name=row.get(i);
        attributes.put("tmplattribute", name); //There are my problem I think
    }
}
```

`getRow()` method obtains data from db and row item store value of `column`.

In my template, that is the combobox code:

```
<p>Choose one: 
    <select name="combo">
        <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected"> </option>
        <option value="${tmplattribute}">${tmplattibute}</option>
    </select>
</p>
```

Is there a way to fill that combobox with all data? At the moment I only get the last row because 'attributes' parameter is a (key,value) data and i can only store one value for that key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Daniel! Your answer show my the way to solve my problem,

If I use your  template code I get a combobox for eache object from the list but if I change ther order like this:

```
<select name="combo">
    <#list mylist as it>
        <#list it as tmplattribute>
            <option value="${tmplattribute}">${tmplattribute}</option>
        </#list>
    </#list>
</select>
```

I obtain what I need. Again thank you because your answer show me the way.

Answer (score 3):

```
List<ArrayList<String>> columna = con.getColumn("table", "column");
attributes.put("mylist", columna);
```

then in your freemarker template

```
<#list mylist as it>
    <select name="combo">
        <#list it as tmplattribute>
            <option value="${tmplattribute}">${tmplattribute}</option>
        </#list>
    </select>
</#list>
```

[Here](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_list.html) you can check the freemarker docs.